# How can I get a custom org drawer to open/close?

Tags: org-mode

My drawers don't seem to collapse with TAB. I've even tried the [canonical example](http://orgmode.org/manual/Drawers.html#Drawers):

```
* This is a headline
  Still outside the drawer
  :DRAWERNAME:
  This is inside the drawer.
  :END:
  After the drawer.
```

When I place the cursor on the line `:DRAWERNAME:` and hit `TAB` nothing happens:

[image]

Also, when I place the cursor on the headline and press `TAB` repeatedly, I cycle through the following two states:

[image]

... and:

[image]

In other words the entire headline appears collapsed but the drawer itself is never collapsed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to tell `org` about any custom drawer names you want to use by customizing `org-drawers`:

> `org-drawers` is a variable defined in `org.el`.
>   Its value is ("PROPERTIES" "CLOCK" "LOGBOOK" "RESULTS")
>
> Documentation:
>   Names of drawers.  Drawers are not opened by cycling on the headline above.
>   Drawers only open with a TAB on the drawer line itself.
>
> (blah blah blah)
>
> The drawer "PROPERTIES" is special for capturing properties through
>   the property API.

With the default, the `:PROPERTIES:` drawer will toggle, but the drawer `:DRAWERNAME:` will not.  However, you can `(add-to-list 'org-drawers "DRAWERNAME")`, restart `org-mode` (`M-x org-mode`), and it will recognize the latter as well.

Comment: Newer org versions appear to have done away with `org-drawers` in favour of `org-drawer-regexp`. When I create a drawer named `foobar`, I can open and close it with the tab key just fine. (My org version is 8.3beta. I live dangerously and update it directly from the git repo at irregular intervals.)

Comment: The org-mode 8.3 [removed](http://orgmode.org/Changes.html#orgheadline22) the need to specify custom drawers.

Comment: @erikstokes and Harald -- great, I was working with 8.2.  Perhaps one of you can add another answer to highlight the changes with the new version?

Answer (score 14):

As of org-mode version [8.3](http://orgmode.org/Changes.html#orgheadline22) this Just Works without needing to set anything.

Before you had to tell org-mode the names of your custom drawers (as per @Dan's answer) to make the work.  The `org-drawers` variable and `#+DRAWERS` keyword are now obsolete.

Comment: Note: as of now, Emacs 25.1 is shipped with Org 8.2 built-in, but Org 8.3 can be installed from the gnu packages collection.